# How to have Greasemonkey script click on a-href without specific ID or class

Tags: jquery, greasemonkey

I want to target a specific a-href attribute with Greasemonkey and have it clicked after the page loads.

The site build is as follows (though obviously simplified, all relevant id's / classes / attributes are included):

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div></div>
    <table class=“things”>
      <tbody>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
            <td>
              <table>
                <tbody>
                  <tr></tr>
                  <tr id=“name11317220”>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>
                      <a href=“?id=11317220” onclick="$('#name11317220').remove();">
                        <b>text</b>
                      </a>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr id=“name83493894”></tr>
               </tbody>
             </table>
             <p></p>
             <div></div>
           </td>
           <td></td>
         </tr>
       </tbody>
     </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

(Yes I know, the website is old and horridly coded)

What I want to do is have the script click on the link which is located in the second td element within tr with id name11317220. However: the number after 'name' is dynamic so I can't just target the id with the name 'name11317220'. The only way (I see) to target it is to have the script click on the a-href within the second child within the first tr element *starting with* 'name'.

Basically I want the script automatically go to webpage.com/test.php?id=11317220, when the specific name of the id constantly changes on reload.

How do I accomplish this?

Edit: added a screenshot of the actual html code in case I missed something in the code.

[image: website code]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `name` part of the `id` attribute on the `tr` is static, then you can select that and navigate down the DOM to the `a`:

```
$('tr[id^="name"]:has(td > a) > td > a')[0].click();
```

Note that this causes a native `click` event, not a jQuery one as the latter will only be caught if a jQuery event handler is bound to the element which, given the use of an `onclick` attribute, does not appear to be the case.

Comment: the name attribute is dynamic and it is listed multiple times on the website with different numbers. Your solution won't work because the number keeps changing

Comment: Ah, understood. I edited the question to select the `tr` where the `id` *starts with* `name` and it contains an `a` element as a child of the `td`. Hopefully that's a big more accurate for your needs

Comment: thanks for the edit, however, it doesn't seem to be working in Greasemonkey (haven't added any other code and I even changed id^="name" to id="name11317220" to check). The script doesn't seem to be clicking on anything and the page isn't reloading. I can't check with console.log due to some issue with Greasemonkey. I added a screenshot of the actual code in my question. Maybe that helps.

Comment: Do you know if the content of the table is added dynamically to the page, via AJAX for example?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. Can I check that somehow? The website is quite old, I think it hasn't been updated for quite a few years. The basic structure has been the same ever since ±2010.

Comment: The most obvious sign is that the site loads and then a second or so later the content appears. You can also see the AJAX request being made in dev tools. If this is what's happening then the issue is because when you try and trigger the click event the element doesn't exist, and you need to delay your JS from running.

Comment: I just wanted to thank you for your time, I've done it in a different way not relevant to this question, so I'm no longer in need of an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can target the class on the outer table, and use a partial attribute matcher on the tr id, before finding the nested link.

```js
console.log(
  $('.things tr[id^="name"] a').get()
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="things">
      <tbody>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
            <td>
              <table>
                <tbody>
                  <tr></tr>
                  <tr id="name11317220">
                    <td></td>
                    <td>
                      <a href="?id=11317220" onclick="$('#name11317220').remove();">
                        <b>text</b>
                      </a>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr id="name83493894"></tr>
               </tbody>
             </table>
             <p></p>
             <div></div>
           </td>
           <td></td>
         </tr>
       </tbody>
     </table>
```

Comment: I just wanted to thank you for your time, I've done it in a different way not relevant to this question, so I'm no longer in need of an answer :)